# python generators in lists can't use it

Tags: python

I have created a list like this:

```
z=[5,4]
```

and I need to assign this list values to another lists and set the elements of z list to the first elements of that lists so I do so :

```
other.append([i,0,'tweak'] for i in z)
```

but it keeps generate something like that :

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x024B7F30>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x02562288>]
```

I could not use my other list at this form !

i expected that my other list look like :

```
[[5,0,'tweak'][4,0,'tweak']]
```

Comment: As for now, your code yields `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please provide us MCVE.

Comment: Post real code. The square brackets don't match.

Comment: i don't want to add the list to another list i already added my list to other list not it's look like [[[]]]

Comment: Edited sorry for that

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Show expected result.

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath already added my expectation

Comment: That's not syntactically correct (try it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ?

```
z=[5,4]
other = [] # or some list
other += [[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z]
```

Answer (score 4):

`[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z` is a generator expression. There is no explicit iterable type declared (list which is denoted by square brackets `[l1, l2]`) - interpreter detects it and creates object which computes values on demand - a generator.

If you want to create list, you must declare it explicitly.

```
other.append([[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z])  # appends list, not generator
```

Comment: The question was updated, rendering this answer obsolate.

Answer (score 3):

**Notes:**

- `[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z` creates a generator function and not a `List Comprehension` to convert it you could add brackets `i.e. [[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z]`
- Now coming to the second problem when first is rectified `[[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z]` creates a `lists of list [[LOL]]` and when you append into a list it becomes `lists of lists of list [[[LOLOL]]]` to avoid that you can use `append`

You could do this

**Code:**

```
z=[5,4]
other=[]
other.extend([[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z])
print other
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using append at all here, since you want to construct your list directly. Just use a list comprehension:

```
other = [[i,0,'tweak'] for i in z]
```